# Starting Cosmology Master's Programme

Tags: cosmology, resource-recommendations, education

I am a Pure Mathematics senior undergraduate student at the university, and I am planning to change my major for master's degree, and one of my alternatives is Cosmology. The problem is that I do not have any background in Physics in general and in Cosmology in particular. In this regard, I have some questions:

$1-$ Is it vital for me to hold a bachelor's in Physics or I can manage the essential courses on my own?

$2-$ Which topics in Physics should I be familiar with to start master's degree is Cosmology?

$3-$ Approximately, How much time does learning these topics take?

$4-$ Which books do you recommend for starting with? and which books do you recommend for gaining further knowledge? (PS: as I can get all of these books out of our university, the price of them is not a factor)

I would really appreciate it if someone could possibly help me find my way!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67428/discussion-on-question-by-c-b-starting-cosmology-masters-programme).

Comment: I've closed this question as a duplicate of a book recommendation question since the rest of your questions is off-topic here as primarily opinion-based and being about study/career advice, not physics as such.